# Insert a calendar in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, calendar

How can I insert a calendar in MS Word (2003)?

I need in the file a calendar from data A till date B. Will be used in a project schedule doc.

I'd like that a calendar like this be like a table, that I could place in a page after or before some text.

Answer (score 1):

```
File => New
```

A task pane will open to the right; click on `On My Computer`. Select the `Other Documents` tab and then click on `Calendar Wizard` The wizard will open in a new box. Click on the `Next` button to continue...

Read more: [How to Create a Calendar in Microsoft Word 2003](http://www.ehow.com/how_4530412_create-calendar-microsoft-word-2003.html)

**It's a pity** that a calendar like this takes a month/page, when I would like some months per page and to put it above/before other text, when actually this takes all the page area.